# Setting $N=1$ and $N^a=0$ in the Einstein-Hilbert action

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, gauge, adm-formalism

In the ADM formalism of general relativity, one obtains a $3+1$ split of spacetime by setting $$\mathrm d s^2=(-N^2+N_a N^a) \,\mathrm d t^2 + 2N_a\,\mathrm d t\,\mathrm d x^a + q_{ab} \,\mathrm d x^a\,\mathrm d x^b \text{.}$$ The Einstein-Hilbert action $$S[N,N^a,q_{ab}]=\int\sqrt{\mathrm{det}(g)}\,R\,\mathrm d^4x$$ is then expressed in terms of $N$, $N^a$ and $q_{ab}$ by pulling all quantities back to $\mathbb R\times\sigma$. Can I just set $N=1$ and $N^a=0$ in the action in order to remove the diffeomorphism invariance or does this somehow modify the system? For instance: Can the Kerr metric be put in this form by a diffeomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it might depend a bit on what you mean and how you will use it, but I think in a strict sense to what you wrote in your question, the answer is that you will generically change the system if you set lapse and shift in the action prior to taking the variational derivatives that give the equations of motion for the fields.

To get *all* of the information in the Einstein equations, you need to take the variation of the action with respect to lapse and shift.  Those variations give you, respectively, the Hamiltonian and the momentum constraints that need to be satisfied on each time slice.  Those are 4 of the 10 independent equations.  I don't see where you will get those constraints out of the variational principle if you set lapse and shift in the action from the start.  At best you need to put those equations back into the system by hand somehow.

If you start with initial data that *does* satisfy the constraints, then it's provable that the constraints propagate, meaning they remain satisfied for all of time.  If you start with initial data that does not satisfy the constraints (perhaps because you dropped those equations by prematurely setting lapse and shift), then all bets are off.  Moreover, there are different flavors of 3+1 decomposition that go under the generic name of ADM.  These are all equivalent if and only if the constraints are satisfied, but if you drop the constraints then you can have different dynamics of the fields given any specific set of initial data.

(This happens in part because the constraints, when satisfied, are 0, so they can be freely added anywhere in the derivation for convenience *if you assume they will be satisfied*.  If not satisfied, however, you're then adding non-zero terms to your evolution equations at those points in your derivation.)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do that, and people did pretty much exactly that when first trying to canonically quantize gravity. These are what is called ``Gaussian normal coordinates''. For a nice, detailed introduction to the strategy in the 3+1 formalism of canonical gravity, check https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0703035 (especially section 4.4, where they do exactly what you are proposing).

Now, even if you do that, you cannot forget that you started with a theory that was diff-invariant; therefore, even though you chose to write the theory in terms of variables that explicitly spoil that gauge symmetry, you still will have to deal with the constraints that are inherited by diff-invariance. There is also the more subtle issue of not generally being able to cover the whole of spacetime using a single patch of Gaussian normal coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do that. I believe it is called the synchronous gauge.

Comment: Thanks! But then I don't understand why don't people don't do this in quantum gravity? It seems to me that the complicated hypersurface deformation constraint algebra would then be replaced by a true Hamiltonian and there would be no problem of time anymore.

Comment: I guess because quantum fluctuations destroy the synchronous gauge construct. This helped me to understand the whole problem a bit better.http://www.thp.uni-koeln.de/gravitation/data/canonical.pdf